# What is the best way to use Restful and CDI working together?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, cdi

I tried to build a project using CDI and Restful working together (Publish a Restful service from a CDI bean) but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Somebody know how they can work together without EJBs?.

Comment: POJO's with JDBC comes to mind.

Comment: I don't understand your point, why JDBC?

Comment: You question needs more detail. I assumed you would need database interaction. You can use CDI to inject JDBC resources into POJO's for example.

Comment: No way, I need publish a Restful service using CDI beans.

Comment: CDI quite often are associated with state and lifecycles. RESTful services are typically by design stateless.

Comment: Your question lacks detail.

Comment: @JoD you have a point but, what about CDI scopes?

Comment: It is the scopes that associate a lifecycle to your beans. Anyway - you are going to have a lifecycle associated with a RESTful service for the duration of the request. Potentially you could have extended lifecycles accross several service calls, but I do not know if the API's are going to support all that. I would think not, because in most cases you would call into a RESTful service through a simple http GET, not from a browser, but from an other program, without all the wiring to maintain a session.

Comment: BTW ... why do you not make some attempt at it, something really simple and basic, and post your code?

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused about the intent.  Since CDI requires a container anyway and since REST web services can be implemented in EJB's (which also require a container) ... well ... why wouldn't you use EJBs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With talking about Restful, I assume you mean Jax-RS. Take a the following code:

**UserResource.java**

This class implements the RESTful API accessing a use case **GetUser** and returning its result.

```
@Path("users")
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserResource {

    @Inject
    private GetUser getUser;

    @GET
    public Response getUser(@QueryParam("userId") String userId) {
        return UserRepresentationMapper.toRepresentation(getUser.getUser(userId);
    }
}
```

**GetUser.java**

The **GetUser** use case uses some dependencies (here a **UserService**) to get its data and do something with it.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class GetUser {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    public ApplicationUser getUser(String userId) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and have a [`beans.xml`](https://gist.github.com/sejersbol/845053) within your `META-INF` (jar) or `WEB-INF` (war) directory to activate CDI (JEE6, `beans.xml` is not needed when using JEE7 and all your classes are annotated with bean [defining annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)).

Comment: Thank you, I add an socpe annotation over the UserResource class and it works.

Comment: Except when I try to do this (i.e have application scoped CDI bean and have application scoped restful service that injects that), I am getting two copies of that application scoped CDI bean: One is created when the application starts - and that is the one that the Restful bean gets injected, and another one is created when the user starts interacting with the app from web interactions using CDI session beans that also inject that CDI Application bean. What a shame. :( (using EE8)

Comment: Oh, I realized the reason. One of the methods in the application scoped CDI bean was not public. It was in the same package, so it could be called, but when it was called from a session scoped CDI bean, a new copy of application scoped CDI bean was created! After the method was made public, now I am getting only one instance of application scoped CDI bean.